# How to fit a two View components inside a View component with borderRadius?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, user-interface, view

I want to divide a circular View in half with 2 different colored Views which will result with circular View containing two background colors. Let's say we fill the main circular View with two Views: blue and red one. Giving both the  blue and red View, the property `flex:1` , means they will take up the same amount of space. Problem is they don't fit the style properties of the main View. (borderRadius is problematic)

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View
              style={{
                height: 300,
                width: 300,
                backgroundColor: "pink",
                borderRadius: 300,
                justifyContent: "center",
                marginTop:60
              }}
            >
              <Text style={{ textAlign: "center", fontSize: 150 }}>❤️</Text>
      </View>

    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can add 2 views with flex:1 and have different background color . Just add overflow: "hidden" to main view**

**Complete code**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text } from "react-native";

export default class Dashboard extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          flexDirection: "column",
          marginVertical: 60,
          marginHorizontal: 30,
          width: 300,
          height: 300,
          borderRadius: 150,
          overflow: "hidden"
        }}
      >
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "#ffbecb" }} />
        <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "blue" }} />
        <View
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            left: 0,
            right: 0,
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            top: 0,
            bottom: 0
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ fontSize: 80 }}> ❤️ </Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Check the code below.

The 'border[Top|Bottom][Left|Right]Radius' style properties enable you to draw a half circle. Just put them in a column under each other.
The text has to be drawn on top with 'absolute' positioning, as you are drawing two Views.

It's probably cleaner to parametrise this code; extracting it as a functional component and creating parameters for size, color, ...

```
render() {
return (
<View style={{flexDirection: 'column', marginTop: 60, width: 300, height: 300}}>
    { /* Top circle half */ }
    <View
            style={{
              height: '50%',
              width: '100%',
              backgroundColor: "pink",
              borderTopLeftRadius: 150,
              borderTopRightRadius: 150
            }}
          >
    { /* Bottom circle half */ }
    </View>
          <View
            style={{
              height: '50%',
              width: '100%',
              backgroundColor: "blue",
              borderBottomLeftRadius: 150,
              borderBottomRightRadius: 150
            }}
          >
    </View>
    { /* Text container */ }
    <View style={{position: 'absolute', left: 0, right: 0, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', top: 0, bottom: 0}}>
      <Text> ❤️ </Text>
    </View>
  </View>
);
```

}